# Crashlytics no longer uploads mapping file when using Android App Bundle

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics, android-app-bundle

When running `Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / SDK`
And then selecting `Android App Bundle`

It generates a new `myApp.aab` File using the play store signing feature. As well as the regular mapping files in `myApp/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt`

For some reason, Crashlytics is not able to pick those up.
Is there any way to manually trigger the uploading process of the Crashlytics?

Tested on

- Gradle build: 3.2.1
- Crashlytics:  2.9.8
- io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+
- Android Studio 3.2.1(Windows)

Comment: Have you tried first building it as an APK? Then building it as a bundle.

Comment: What Fabric Gradle Plugin are you on?
Support for uploading for app bundles was only added in 1.26.0 back in September
https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html

Comment: I guess I am on the latest one as I been testing Jan this year(2019). `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+` would probably translate to whatever is available.

Comment: Hi, anything new here? Did anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fabric finally fixed that bug in [1.31.0](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#july-24-2019)

> **1.31.0: July 24, 2019**
>   - Fixed mapping file uploads for Dexguard users building Android App Bundles (requires Dexguard 8.5).
>   - Fixed an issue which, when building Android App Bundles, caused APK builds to be triggered as well.
>   - Fixed an issue preventing Fabric API keys defined in a fabric.properties file from being injected properly for Android App Bundle builds.

I've faced the same problem and after updating the version it was fixed:

```
buildscript {
  ...
  classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used App Bundle before; however, I want you to try uploading the mapping file `myApp/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt` to Play Store Console -> Android vitals -> Deobfuscation files.

[image]

Good luck!.

Comment: Yeah, I do that, but it's not in sync with crashalitics

Comment: Android app bundle already contains mapping files, so there is no need to add them here manually https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle > BUNDLE-METADATA/: This directory includes metadata files that contain information useful for tools or app stores. Such metadata files may include ProGuard mappings and the complete list of your app's DEX files...

Comment: @repitch Do you know when and from which AGP version this change was introduced? This is a powerful feature but I don't think they advertised anywhere about this.